# Dynamically transpose rows into columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have a simple entity attribut value table with 3 columns 1) policyholder_locator; 2) field_name; 3) field_value. Sample data as follows:

```
policyholder_locator,field_name,field_value
1,first_name,john
1,phone,8888888888
1,email,john@gmail.com
2,first_name,jane
2,phone,7777777777
2,email,jane@gmail.com
3,first_name,joe
3,phone,6666666666
3,email,joe@gmail.com
```

I would ideally like to use the following GROUP_CONCAT and prepared statements code, but I keep getting the following error when running "An SQLException was provoked by the following failure: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException".

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
            'MAX(CASE WHEN field_name = ''',
            field_name,
            ''' THEN field_value END) ',
            field_name
        )
    ) INTO @sql
FROM policyholder_fields;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT policyholder_locator, ',@sql, '
    FROM policyholder_fields
    GROUP BY policyholder_locator');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I could go with code that's not dynamic like below, but would prefer a dynamic option.

```
SELECT policyholder_locator, 
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_name = 'phone', field_value, NULL)) AS phone, 
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_name = 'email', field_value, NULL)) AS email, 
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_name = 'first_name', field_value, NULL)) AS first_name 
FROM policyholder_fields  
GROUP BY policyholder_locator
```

Is there an obvious issue with my prepared statements?

Comment: Your first SELECT has no FROM clause. Column names come from the `information_schema.COLUMNS` system table.

Comment: The code works https://dbfiddle.uk/jGTtx3v1 so I don't think it's a MySQL problem.

Comment: Thank you! That actually helps me narrow down where I need to investigate.